# What would happen if a male had the Female Titan power in 'Attack on Titans'?

Tags: plot-explanation, attack-on-titan

**Warning : This post contains spoilers for AoT season 2**

So in season 2 of AoT we learn that :

> Ymir is able to transform into a Titan just like Eren

And

> One of the corpse member's mother is found as a Titan

So we know that women can be Titans and that anyone

> who is transformed into a Titan and eats someone who has the ability to go from Titan to Human will steal that power regardless of one's sex

So my question is : If any female can become a Titan what is the Female Titan specificity ? Is she a Titan that can only be handled by women specifically ? Has there been any word from the author about that subject ?

Comment: What episodes shows that a Titan eating another titan gains the eaten titan's powers?

Comment: The one where you see Ymir eating you-know-who's friend and then turning back into human

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based solely on informations available in the anime, putting aside all informations from the manga

The Female Titan was primarily defined by her appearance : to put it in a crude way, it's the first, and for now only, titan with breasts.

But we can see this titan use two abilities.

First one :

> Calling classic titans to eat her

But we have no sign that this capacity is specific to her

Second one :

> The ability to harden skin into an unbreakable cristal

This ability on the other hand has never been seen used by another titan in the show.

> Their are similarities with the armored titan. But this one does not control his armor this well. And contrary to the cristal, this armor has been shown to be breakable.

Comment: Anymore information that's be from the manga ?

Comment: I'm not up to date, so no. Plus manga and anime might (and probably will) diverge on several points.

Comment: All titans can harden. They plan on Eren hardening to repair the wall, and the wall is made up of hardened titans.

Comment: Eren needed the serum they stole previously to harden. He doesn't have that power to begin with

Comment: Slight tweak to the answer during S3, but avoiding spoilers: it is proven that Eren _can_ harden without the liquid. The liquid simply jumpstarted Eren's not yet developed ability. All titans can harden, if they unlock the ability. It is suggested but not confirmed that it can be learned without the serum.